# How to get Apple JWT token expiration date from Graph API?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

We are using Sign In with Apple.  The automated token renewal has failed in the past.  I want to query the Graph API for the token expiration date so it can be tracked in our monitoring system.

EDIT:  After contacting Azure support, the root cause for the token failing to auto renew is that we are using a custom user flow (IEF) policy

Answer (score 0):

While generating the access token, you can see an attribute called **`expires_in`** along with access token.

> **You can make use of below **CURL script** to get the Apple JWT token:**

```
curl -v POST "https://appleid.apple.com/auth/token" \
-H 'content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
-d 'client_id=CLIENT_ID' \-d 'client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET' \
-d 'code=CODE' \-d 'grant_type=authorization_code' \
-d 'redirect_uri=REDIRECT_URI'
```

You will get **response** like below:

```
{ "access_token": "adg61...67Or9", 
"token_type": "Bearer", 
"expires_in": 3600, 
"refresh_token": "rca7...lABoQ" 
"id_token": "eyJra...96sZg"}
```

In the above response you can find expiration time in **`expires_in`** attribute.

**Otherwise**, you can decode the token by using [**JSON Web Tokens - jwt.io**](https://jwt.io/) site like below:

Copy the access token and paste it in **encoded field**.

[image]

Under **payload section**, you can find expiration date in **`exp`** attribute.

For more information, please **refer** below link:

[Generate and Validate Tokens | Apple Developer Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sign_in_with_apple/generate_and_validate_tokens)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.  I don't think I have direct access to the secret, only the client ID.  The token is managed by Azure AD B2C, which is why I need to query the Graph.  I've found a Microsoft [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/identityproviderbase-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#example-3-retrieves-apple-identity-provideronly-for-azure-ad-b2c) which may help

Answer (score 0):

{
"access_token": "adg61...67Or9",
"token_type": "Bearer",
"expires_in": 3600,
"refresh_token": "rca7...lABoQ",
"id_token": "eyJra...96sZg"
}

Comment: this... is an answer to the question?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).